# I'm trying to write an audio file in Octave, but the error keeps popping up

Tags: audio, octave

I am trying to write an audio file containing a C-major scale. I'm a newbie in Octave, I'm not sure how to do this, so I did my coding like this, Appreciate the help, thanks:

```
# Scale Frequencies
x_1 = 261.6256;
x_2 = 293.6648;
x_3 = 329.6276;
x_4 = 349.2282;
x_5 = 391.9954;
x_6 = 440.0000;
x_7 = 493.8833;

X = [x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7];


fs = 2*44100; T = 0.1;
t = [0 : 1/fs : T];
A = 0.5;
x = A .* sin(2 .* pi .* X .* t);

audiowrite('musicnotes', X, fs)
```

Despite adding dots before all the operators, all I get is this:

> error: product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x7, op2 is 1x8821)
> error: called from    Lab02_Task02 at line 16 column 3

Comment: I’d recommend checking the [`[octave]` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boctave%5D+nonconformant) for the key word `nonconformant`. From the error you know it is on line 16. So I would ask yourself _what is my expected output of `X .* t`_

Comment: Also if the file is `Lab02_Task02` ask the staff at your institute for guidance, not answer, but guidance. If you don’t engage with staff now it will only get harder as the semester progresses